# Autoinstall support both EFI and Legacy boot

Tags: grub2, 22.04, uefi, curtin

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 using [Autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall). My generated ISO that includes userdata.yml (main autoinstall's file) has `storage` section, that **should** support **both** EFI and Legacy boot, but I cannot find a way to implement it.

Storage section in userdata.yml that supports **only** EFI boot:

```
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: false
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1127219200
      wipe: superblock
      flag: boot
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: true
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - fstype: fat32
      volume: partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1073741824
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-1
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 54760833024
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
    - name: myvg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: slashlv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 53687091200B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-2
    - path: /
      device: format-2
      type: mount
      id: mount-2
    - path: /boot
      device: format-1
      type: mount
      id: mount-1
    - path: /boot/efi
      device: format-0
      type: mount
      id: mount-0
```

Storage section in userdata.yml that supports **only** Legacy boot:

```
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1073741824
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-1
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 54760833024
      wipe: superblock
      flag: ''
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
    - name: myvg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: slashlv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 53687091200B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-2
    - path: /
      device: format-2
      type: mount
      id: mount-1
    - path: /boot
      device: format-1
      type: mount
      id: mount-0
```

My failure when I'm trying to install EFI with userdata.yml that supports only legacy boot (and the opposite) -

```
2022-11-03 09:48:37,448 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/Filesystem/apply_autoinstall_config: FAIL: autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition
2022-11-03 09:48:37,448 ERROR root:39 finish: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: FAIL: autoinstall config did not create needed bootloader partition
```

Again, I need to support **both** EFI and Legacy boot, in the **same** userdata.yml file.

Thanks!

Comment: Am I misreading this you have the exact same info twice. From your question "Storage section in userdata.yml that supports only EFI boot:" this and the post after seems to be exactly the same .

Comment: I just wrote EFI twice, the yml is a bit different. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I deleted the whole `storage` section in `user-data`; The default autoinstall "knows" how to deal with it whether you are running in a UEFI system or a Legacy BIOS.

Note: It creates the following as default -

```
/boot - 2g
(If UEFI) /boot/efi - 1g±
/ - as LVM - 100g, or if your disk is less than 100g, it creates it with about 70% of the disk's size.
VG name - ubuntu-vg
LV name (that mounted to /) - ubuntu-lv
```

Comment: If you delete the whole `storage` config then the installer (subiquity) will use an `lvm` `layout` configuration [by default](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/c03b23d7e4aa66a25252a1de1578c5ab099f1667/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py#L142).

Answer (score 4):

Officially, you can't create a single storage config that supports both BIOS and UEFI.  The `grub_device` settings are incompatible.  Quoting from one of the [installer (subiquity) developers](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/please-test-autoinstalls-for-20-04/15250/367?u=alowther)

> Yes, probably. I actually wanted to clean this whole area up and make
> the config saner (for example, it really ought to be possible to
> install a system that will boot both legacy and UEFI) but it doesn’t
> look like I’m going to get around to that any time soon…

As a workaround, `early-commands` can be used to make a single config work.  Here is a sample `user-data` snippet that I have used.  It will modify the `/autoinstall.yaml` file depending on the existence of `/sys/firmware/efi`.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  storage:
    config:
    - type: disk
      match:
        size: largest
      ptable: gpt
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      id: disk-sda
    - type: partition
      device: disk-sda
      size: 4194304
      wipe: superblock
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 14
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      id: partition-14
    - type: partition
      device: disk-sda
      size: 111149056
      wipe: superblock
      flag: boot
      number: 15
      preserve: false
      grub_device: UEFI
      id: partition-15
    - type: partition
      device: disk-sda
      size: -1
      wipe: superblock
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      id: partition-1
    - type: format
      fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      id: format-1
    - type: mount
      path: /
      device: format-1
      id: mount-1
    - type: format
      fstype: fat32
      volume: partition-15
      preserve: false
      id: format-15
    - type: mount
      path: /boot/efi
      device: format-15
      id: mount-15
  early-commands:
    - |
      if [ -e "/sys/firmware/efi" ]; then
        sed -i -e "s/grub_device: UEFI/grub_device: true/" /autoinstall.yaml
      else
        sed -i -e "s/grub_device: UEFI/grub_device: false/" /autoinstall.yaml
      fi
      true
```

With this snippet all devices will end up with the same partition layout, which could be confusing.  For example, a BIOS based machine will still end up with an unnecessary ESP partition mounted at `/boot/efi`, and a UEFI based machine will have an unnecessary `bios_grub` partition.

The [cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/) have a [partition layout](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/buildd/hooks/02-disk-image-uefi.binary?id=997fd08e628219a277c0e67a9af5bf7dc0031c7f#n30) that was used as inspiration for this config.  The cloud images support both BIOS and UEFI and I wanted to duplicate that.  The resulting partition table looks like this, where the final partition fills the disk.

```
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start    End       Size      File system  Name  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  5.00MiB   4.00MiB                      bios_grub
 2      5.00MiB  111MiB    106MiB    fat32              boot, esp
 3      111MiB   20479MiB  20368MiB  ext4
```

Comment: Can you please clarify in my example of `user-data` what should be added in the `early-commands` section? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I used to create autoinstall for ubuntu22.04：

```
  early-commands:
- |
  cat << EOF | python3
  import yaml
  import os

  mbr_disk0 = {'id': 'root-disk', 'ptable': 'gpt', 'type': 'disk', 'match': {'size': 'largest'}, 'wipe': 'superblock-recursive', 'preserve': False, 'grub_device': True, 'name': 'rnxtdisk'}
  mbr_part0 = {'id': 'partition-0', 'type': 'partition', 'device': 'root-disk', 'size': '1M', 'flag': 'bios_grub', 'number': 1, 'preserve': False}
  efi_disk0 = {'id': 'root-disk', 'ptable': 'gpt', 'type': 'disk', 'match': {'size': 'largest'}, 'wipe': 'superblock-recursive', 'preserve': False, 'grub_device': False, 'name': 'rnxtdisk'}
  efi_part0 = {'id': 'partition-0', 'type': 'partition', 'device': 'root-disk', 'grub_device': True, 'size': '1G', 'flag': 'boot', 'number': 1, 'preserve': False}
  part1     = {'id': 'partition-1', 'type': 'partition', 'device': 'root-disk', 'size': '1G', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'number': 2, 'preserve': False}
  part2     = {'id': 'partition-2', 'type': 'partition', 'device': 'root-disk', 'size': -1, 'wipe': 'superblock', 'number': 3, 'preserve': False}
  vg0       = {'name': 'vg0', 'devices': ['partition-2'], 'preserve': False, 'id': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'type': 'lvm_volgroup'}
  lv_root   = {'name': 'lv-root', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '10G', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'lvm_partition-0', 'type': 'lvm_partition'}
  fmt_root  = {'fstype': 'xfs', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-0', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-2', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_root  = {'path': '/', 'device': 'format-2', 'id': 'mount-2', 'type': 'mount'}
  lv_home   = {'name': 'lv-home', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '5G', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'lvm_partition-1', 'type': 'lvm_partition'}
  fmt_home  = {'fstype': 'xfs', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-1', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-3', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_home  = {'path': '/home', 'device': 'format-3', 'id': 'mount-3', 'type': 'mount'}
  lv_data   = {'name': 'lv-data', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '10G', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'lvm_partition-2', 'type': 'lvm_partition'}
  fmt_data  = {'fstype': 'xfs', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-2', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-4', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_data  = {'path': '/data', 'device': 'format-4', 'id': 'mount-4', 'type': 'mount'}
  fmt_boot  = {'fstype': 'xfs', 'volume': 'partition-1', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-1', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_boot  = {'path': '/boot', 'device': 'format-1', 'id': 'mount-1', 'type': 'mount'}
  fmt_efi   = {'fstype': 'fat32', 'volume': 'partition-0', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-0', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_efi   = {'path': '/boot/efi', 'device': 'format-0', 'id': 'mount-0', 'type': 'mount'}
  lv_docker = {'name': 'lv-lib-docker', 'volgroup': 'lvm_volgroup-0', 'size': '10G', 'wipe': 'superblock', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'lvm_partition-3', 'type': 'lvm_partition'}
  fmt_docker = {'fstype': 'xfs', 'volume': 'lvm_partition-3', 'preserve': False, 'id': 'format-6', 'type': 'format'}
  mnt_docker = {'path': '/var/lib/docker', 'device': 'format-6', 'id': 'mount-6', 'type': 'mount'}

  boot_fs = [fmt_boot, mnt_boot]
  root_fs = [lv_root, fmt_root, mnt_root]
  home_fs = [lv_home, fmt_home, mnt_home]
  data_fs = [lv_data, fmt_data, mnt_data]
  docker_fs = [lv_docker, fmt_docker, mnt_docker]

  common_storage_part = [part1, part2, vg0] + boot_fs + root_fs + home_fs + data_fs + rlog_fs + docker_fs

  with open('/autoinstall.yaml') as reader:
    autoinstall = yaml.safe_load(reader)

  autoinstall['storage'].clear()

  with open('/autoinstall.yaml', 'w') as writer:
    if os.path.exists('/sys/firmware/efi'):
      autoinstall['storage'].update({'config': [efi_disk0, efi_part0, fmt_efi, mnt_efi] + common_storage_part })
    else:
      autoinstall['storage'].update({'config': [mbr_disk0, mbr_part0] + common_storage_part })
    yaml.dump(autoinstall, writer)

  EOF
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).