# Add UEFI partition and legacy BIOS partition to storage of autoinstall

Tags: user-data

I have an requirement of having both EFI and legacy bios boot partitions in storage section of autoinstall so that depending on the mode of installation it would proceed but I am not able to create one successfully.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to support both UEFI and BIOS with a single custom storage config.  I do have a work-around using `early-commands` at https://askubuntu.com/q/1438902/376778 and another answer shows that leaving out the storage section can also work for both.

Comment: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios.img.xz will create a BIOS and a UEFI partition on a USB drive and install grub. You can use GParted's copy-and-paste features to put these partitions where you want them.